# mod_perl debugging in a shared environment

Tags: perl, debugging, remote-debugging, mod-perl

I'm working in a shared mod_perl development environment and there is no way I can run apache with -X (attached). Is there any way of attaching the debugger to a particular request/session?

Comment: My response would be don't try to work your way around doing the right thing (setting up a sandbox). I'll be interested to see what others have to say.

Comment: I agree that under normal circumstances there is no excuse not set up a proper dev environment - but there is no way I can do that with this project.

Comment: You can't spend 20 minutes setting up a Linux VM on your local machine and installing mod_perl?

Comment: No - if I could I've done it a long time ago. Seriously not all comes down to "You can't spend 20 minutes setting up a Linux VM" - and how do you know the system even runs on a Linux env?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a new app, why not write (and test) it by writing against the [PSGI interface](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack) so you don't need to pipe it through apache to debug? Once done, you can just run the plack app under mod_perl.

Alternately, if it's a legacy mod_perl application, there appears to be a [Plack::App::FakeApache](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Plack%3a%3aApp%3a%3aFakeApache) module that lets you [debug and profile a mod_perl app](http://peter.makholm.net/2010/11/30/wrapping-mod_perl-in-plack/) against a PSGI server.

Comment: This is an existing massive system that is tightly integrated with other in house modules/parts. Even if I could legally set it up to run on a local dedicated dev environment/sandbox, I doubt it'd be possible, because of its external dependencies. So no, I can't run it locally, nor can I run the code in a separate/different web server set up.